# DOM manipulation using PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm web scraping a web page Using Phantomjs and replacing canvas element with image as follows. but when I try to modify some element's inner HTML to image its not working. Can any one tell me what's wrong?

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');
var URL = 'some web url';

page.open(URL, function(status) {

    if (status !== 'success') {    
        console.log('Unable to access network');
    } else {

        var clipRect = page.evaluate(function() {
            return document.getElementById("some-id").getBoundingClientRect();
        });

        page.clipRect = {
            top : clipRect.top,
            left : clipRect.left,
            width : clipRect.width,
            height : clipRect.height
        };
        page.render('canvas.png');

        // modify one element's inner html before writing into file
        // document.getElementById("some-id").innerHTML = '<img src="capture.png">';

        fs.write('email.html', page.content, 'w');

        phantom.exit();

    }

});
```

PS: New to nodejs and phantomjs

Comment: Please provide the actual code with the manipulation that you're asking about. Please register to the [`onConsoleMessage`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html) and [`onError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html) events. Maybe there are errors.

Comment: PhantomJS has its own execution environment distinct from node. It is only installed through npm for convenience.

Comment: Can you clarify - when you tested the code - what did you expect to happen, and what did happen? What have you tried to do by the way of debugging?

Comment: Above code working except commented code (capturing canvas as img and writing page html into file) But I need know how to edit HTML before writing into file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done using one more page.evaluate to store modified html after canvas element captured as image as follows

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');
var URL = 'some web url';

page.open(URL, function(status) {

    if (status !== 'success') {    
        console.log('Unable to access network');
    } else {

        var clipRect = page.evaluate(function() {
            return document.getElementById("some-id").getBoundingClientRect();
        });

        page.clipRect = {
            top : clipRect.top,
            left : clipRect.left,
            width : clipRect.width,
            height : clipRect.height
        };
        page.render('canvas.png');

        var newHTML = page.evaluate(function() {

            var canvas = document.getElementById("some-id");

            var newCanvas = document.createElement('img');
            newCanvas.setAttribute('src', 'canvas.png');
            newCanvas.setAttribute('alt', 'canvas');

            canvas.innerHTML = newCanvas.outerHTML;

            return document.documentElement.outerHTML;

        });

        fs.write('email.html', newHTML, 'w');

        phantom.exit();

    }
});
```

Comment: It is always good to add a description in addition to the big block of code.